# SQL Server job running an SSIS package - remove \SERVER parameter

Tags: sql-server

I notice when I use the GUI in SSMS to create a jobstep that executes an SSIS package, it builds out the dtexec string with all the parameters, including "\SERVER myServerName".

This will cause problems when my system tables are replicated to another server.

Is there a way I can avoid having the \SERVER parameter added when I use the GUI to create the job?

**Edit - Providing more info:**

We are setting up SAN replication and trying to determine the impact of including msdb on one of the replicated devices.  The problem I'm foreseeing is if the 'command' column of sysjobsteps has the target server hardcoded in the dtexec string then when we fail over it'll try to run the package on the old box rather than the current one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll get a definitive answer for this, but I assume it's simply a feature of the GUI. I would just edit the command line manually to remove the parameter; if you're using a GUI in the first place then presumably an extra step isn't an issue for you.

Alternatively, you could create and maintain batch scripts with exactly the parameters you want and then run them from CmdExec job steps. But then you have to manage the batch scripts, of course.

Finally, you haven't mentioned exactly what your "problems" are. If you remove the /S parameter but "replicate" the job (using multi-server administration?) then you will need to deploy your SSIS packages to every target server too. Maybe this is what you want or already do anyway.